# Firebase Crash Reporting grouping most Xamarin.Android exceptions

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using Firebase Crash Reporting with Xamarin.Forms. I successfully implemented Firebase Crash on my Android app, but most exceptions end up grouped based on `android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Crash Reporting does not support apps that are not built using native code and tools.  It doesn't understand frameworks like Xamarin, so you can expect that it may not be very useful in those environments.  On Android, it only really knows how to deal with native Java stack traces from native code running the app.

Comment: I would suggest using Crashlytics instead

Comment: I understand that it doesn't support Xamarin out of the box, but is it possible to implement a custom parser, or something like that to work around this?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: I ended up using Microsoft's App Center because of this, thank you for your clarification